# Nested deployment of AWS Lambda funtions with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, aws-lambda

I am learning how to deploy AWS Lambda functions from Jenkins.
I have following forlder structure:

```
src -> favorites -> findAll -> index.js
src -> favorites -> insert -> index.js
src -> movies -> findAll -> index.js
src -> movies -> findOne -> index.js
```

Essentially 4x functions.

Here's part of Jenkinsfile:

```
def functions = ['MoviesStoreListMovies', 'MoviesStoreSearchMovie', MoviesStoreViewFavorites', 'MoviesStoreAddToFavorites']
stage('Build'){
            sh """
                docker build -t ${imageName} .
                containerName=\$(docker run -d ${imageName})
                docker cp \$containerName:/app/node_modules node_modules
                docker rm -f \$containerName
                zip -r ${commitID()}.zip node_modules src
            """
}
stage('Push'){
            functions.each { function ->
                sh "aws s3 cp ${commitID()}.zip s3://${bucket}/${function}/"
}
```

At the end I expect to have 4x AWS S3 buckets with same .zip content in it (i.e. all 4 same folders/functions present in each bucket).

Here now my issue. The build stage.

```
 stage('Deploy'){
      functions.each { 
        function ->
         sh "aws lambda update-function-code --function-name ${function} --s3-bucket
         ${bucket} --s3-key ${function}/${commitID()}.zip --region ${region}"
       }
}
```

Since the zip has same content, how can be that the 4 functions are deployed as exactly 4 functions? Again, each of the 4x .zip file contains in turn the same 4x folders/functions. So I would expect 4x4=16 functions eventually.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my mistake. I missed to say that Lambda functions get created with Terraform first. And indeed Terraform creates handlers pointing to the right src paths:

```
  module "MoviesStoreListMovies" {
  source = "./modules/function"
  name = "MoviesStoreListMovies"
  handler = "src/movies/findAll/index.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  environment = {
    TABLE_NAME = aws_dynamodb_table.movies.id
  }
}

module "MoviesStoreSearchMovie" {
  source = "./modules/function"
  name = "MoviesStoreSearchMovie"
  handler = "src/movies/findOne/index.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  environment = {
    TABLE_NAME = aws_dynamodb_table.movies.id
  }
}

module "MoviesStoreViewFavorites" {
  source = "./modules/function"
  name = "MoviesStoreViewFavorites"
  handler = "src/favorites/findAll/index.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  environment = {
    TABLE_NAME = aws_dynamodb_table.favorites.id
  }
}

module "MoviesStoreAddToFavorites" {
  source = "./modules/function"
  name = "MoviesStoreAddToFavorites"
  handler = "src/favorites/insert/index.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  environment = {
    TABLE_NAME = aws_dynamodb_table.favorites.id
  }
}
```